# Cannot enter data into phpmyadmin from Java class

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, android-volley

when I run this code there's no new data in my database. I've already checked my connection and tried it using postman app its working the data entered the database. But when i tried to send data from my xml file to phpmyadmin. there's no new data tht I send in it.

when I checked my `userRegister.php` there's nothing wrong with it.

but still when I try submit the form there's no data in my database. 
and the toast msg appear without any msg just a blank black toast msg.

private EditText editTextUsername, editTextEmail, editTextPassword;
    private Button buttonRegister;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

```
private TextView textViewLogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUsername);
    editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);

    textViewLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewLogin);

    buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);


}

private void registerUser() {
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering user...");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Constants.URL_REGISTER,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                        makeText(getApplicationContext(), jsonObject.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.hide();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("email", email);
            params.put("password", password);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);


}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view == buttonRegister)
        registerUser();
}
```

**registerUser.php**

```
require_once'../includes/DbOperations.php';

$response = array();

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

//check user give all the info required
if(
    isset($_POST['username'])and
        isset($_POST['email']) and
            isset($_POST['password']))

    {
//operate the data further
     //create db operation object

    $db = new DbOperations();

    //call method
    if($db-> createUser(
        $_POST['username'],
        $_POST['password'],
        $_POST['email']
        )){
        $response['error'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "User registered successfully";
    }else{
        $response['error'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "Some error occured please try again";

    }

}else{
    $response['error']= true;
    $response['message']= "Required fields are missing";

}

}else{
    $response['error'] = true;
    $response['message'] = "Invalid Request";
}


//display error in json format
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: have you given internet permission in manifest?

Comment: yes i already insert tht line at manifest.

Comment: @VivekMishra private static final String ROOT_URL = "http://localhost/emumcare/v1";

    public  static final String URL_REGISTER = ROOT_URL+"registerUser.php";

Comment: i already make the connection as above.

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/how-to-run-an-android-app-against-a-localhost-api

Comment: i already change my localhost to my ip address.. but it doesn't work.

Comment: finally i know the problem.... i forgot to put slash inside my connection file... duhhh..